# グラフ上のプロット数

Tags: python

pythonでこのような散布図を描いたのですが今後データ数が増えていきしっかり反映されているか確認するためグラフ上のにあるプロット数を表示する方法を教えていただきたいです．

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.array([0, 6, 11 , 20, 30, 40]) 
y=np.array([92, 105, 114 , 125, 148, 141]) 

#for plot
xnew =np.linspace(0, 40, num=50)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
```

Comment: できればタイトルも質問内容が分かるようなものを心がけてみてください。今回なら「グラフ上のプロット数を表示する方法を知りたい」など。

Answer (score 1):

散布図の場合、x軸の値の個数(質問のコードのxの長さ)と、y軸の値の個数(質問のコードのyの長さ)は、同じにしなくてはいけなくて、その個数がプロットの数になります。
なので、

```
print(len(x))
```

で、プロットの数が表示されます。（単にprintしたので、5 というような素っ気ない表示で画面に出るだけですが）

グラフのタイトルに「xxの散布図（プロット数：５）」なんて書くと、もっと感じが良いですかね。

Answer (score 1):

`xlim` や `ylim` の設定値によっては可視範囲にあるプロット数が異なる場合があります。以下では可視範囲にあるデータ数(プロット数)を返す `num_visible_points()` 関数を定義しています。

```py
>>> def num_visible_points():
      ax = plt.gca()
      xmin, xmax = ax.xaxis.get_view_interval()
      ymin, ymax = ax.yaxis.get_view_interval()
      line = ax.get_lines()
      if not line: return 0
      line = line[0]
      xdata, ydata = line.get_xdata(), line.get_ydata()
      return sum((xdata>=xmin) & (xdata<=xmax) & (ydata>=ymin) & (ydata<=ymax))

>>> plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
>>> num_visible_points()
6
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: 6 points]

```py
>>> plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
>>> plt.xlim(5, 20)
(5.0, 20.0)
>>> num_visible_points()
3
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: 3 points]